# Stata: is there a way to count months between two dates, given in year-month format?

Tags: date, stata

I am trying to simply count the months between two dates in Stata, given in year-month (%tm) format, data storage type being int. Basically, I want to do what the datediff(d1, d1, "month") function does in Stata 17 - except I have Stata 15. I saw a few other forums about this, but they all talked about solutions for a year-month-day format, which doesn't seem to work for me. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This question is wide open without precise details on your data. Does format mean Stata monthly date display format or something else? Are your monthly dates held in one variable or two? Are variables numeric or string. Please read the Stata tag wiki to learn how to give a decent data example.

Comment: The date data is stored in a %tm format variable, I edited the question to add that - the variables are numeric, storage type being int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both variables are numeric and the units are consistent, no special function is needed as a subtraction gives the answer.

```
. clear

. set obs 1
Number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1.

. gen now = ym(2022, 7)

. gen lastyear = ym(2021, 7)

. format now lastyear %tm

. di now - lastyear
12

. gen diff = now - lastyear

. l

     +--------------------------+
     |    now   lastyear   diff |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | 2022m7     2021m7     12 |
     +--------------------------+
```